# Error convert json to datatable in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, datatable, http-post

I am receiving through http post the following string as json:

```
 Dim json As String = "[{" + """name"":""jocelyne" + """," + """mo"":""jocelyne" + """}" + ",{" + """name"":""eliane" + """," + """mo"":""12345678" + """}" + "]"
```

I need to convert this json array to a datatable in vb.net

I tried using NewtonSoft.json.dll :

```
Dim jss As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim deserializedProduct As Dictionary(Of String, String) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(json)
```

but I keep getting there is no source code available for the current location although I added the reference to my project and it's in the bin file ..

the actual error is :

```
Cannot deserialize JSON array into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'.
```

is there a way to fix this or does anyone have another way to convert a json array to a datatable in vb.net?

Comment: @Shruti what's the incorrect in the json?

Comment: you can validate your json using this link http://jsonlint.org/ ..paste your json here and u'll get to know

Comment: @Shruti well my json is valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to deserialize the JSON string into a `Dictionary` which should represent an object, but your JSON string contains an array of two objects instead of a single object.

So you should use `List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))` instead of `Dictionary(Of String, String)`:

**LINQPad:**

```
Sub Main
    Dim json As String = "[{" + """name"":""jocelyne" + """," + """mo"":""jocelyne" + """}" + ",{" + """name"":""eliane" + """," + """mo"":""12345678" + """}" + "]"
    Dim deserializedProduct As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)))(json)
    deserializedProduct.Dump()
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want a `DataTable`, just use

```
Sub Main
    Dim json As String = "[{" + """name"":""jocelyne" + """," + """mo"":""jocelyne" + """}" + ",{" + """name"":""eliane" + """," + """mo"":""12345678" + """}" + "]"
    Dim table As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
    table.Dump()
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: can you please check for me the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535504/json-object-into-a-datatable-and-a-string

Comment: i need to get two datatables