# Json Object into a datatable and a string

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net, datatables, http-post

i have the following json received through http post in asp.net:

```
 {
"Header": {
    "MCC": "415",
    "F0": "0",
    "REG ID": "0" 
},
"Contacts": [
    {
        "name": "jocelyne",
        "mo": "jocelyne"
    },
    {
        "name": "eliane",
        "mo": "12345678"
    }
]
}
```

i need to put only the data under contacts in a datatable and deserialize the data under header into 3 variables...

i tried this :

```
 Dim deserializedProduct As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String)))(json)
```

and this:

```
Dim table As DataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(json)
```

i tried using this json:

```
 {
"Data": [
    {
        "MCC": "415",
        "F0": "0",
        "REG ID": "0"
    }
],
"Contacts": [
    {
        "name": "jocelyne",
        "mo": "jocelyne"
    },
    {
        "name": "eliane",
        "mo": "12345678"
    }
]
}
```

but none of these worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create some classes that matches the data you recieve:

```
Class Data
    Public Header As Header
    Public Contacts As List(Of Contact)
End Class

<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract>
Class Header
    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name := "MCC")>
    Public MCC As Integer
    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name := "F0")>
    Public F0 As Integer
    <System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name := "REG ID")>
    Public RegId As Integer
End Class

Class Contact
    Public Name As String
    Public Mo As String
End Class
```

So it's easy to deserialize the data:

```
Sub Main
    Dim json As String = <json>
                        {
                        "Header": {
                            "MCC": "415",
                            "F0": "0",
                            "REG ID": "0"
                        },
                        "Contacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "jocelyne",
                                "mo": "jocelyne"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "eliane",
                                "mo": "12345678"
                            }
                        ]
                        }</json>.Value


    Dim data As Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Data)(json)
    data.Dump()
End Sub
```

[image]

Now you can easily access the values you're looking for, like `data.Header.MCC` etc.

Note that I use the `DataContract`/`DataMember` here on the `Header` class because otherwise the deserializer has no way to know that `REG ID` should be mapped to `RegId` (since you can't have member names with spaces in VB.Net).

If you really want a `DataTable` for your contacts, just declare `Data.Contacts` as `DataTable`:

```
Class Data
    Public Header As Header
    Public Contacts As DataTable
End Class
```

Comment: I'm getting there is no source code available for the current location

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury This error has nothing to do with this code. Try googling `no source code available for the current location` to find a bunch of informations about this error. Maybe you fiddled on the debug settings of visual studio?